# Question about bundling CentOS RPMs for Perl modules

Tags: linux, perl, redhat, rpm

I am trying to bundle a bunch of Perl modules in RPM packages for easy deployments. I've tried a lot of tools but settled on fpm (https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm).

So I've managed to manually build and install each RPM for each of the required Perl modules. I'm not sure this is correct. But I don't have a lot of experience with RPM packages. But as far as I can tell, this is the correct behavior. Each RPM package contains all required dependencies for the corresponding Perl module.

The problem is I get some conflicts when I try to use the resulting bundle to install my modules.

```
sudo yum --disablerepo=* localinstall *.rpm
```

And when it tries to install:

```
Transaction Summary
==============================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  174 Packages

Total size: 45 M
Installed size: 357 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Error: Transaction test error:
  file /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/Moose/Moose.so conflicts between attempted installs of Moose-Exporter-2.2013-1.x86_64 and Moose-2.2013-1.x86_64
  file /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/Moose/Moose.so conflicts between attempted installs of Moose-Role-2.2013-1.x86_64 and Moose-Exporter-2.2013-1.x86_64
  file /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/Moose/Moose.so conflicts between attempted installs of Moose-Util-TypeConstraints-2.2013-1.x86_64 and Moose-Role-2.2013-1.x86_64
  file /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/Moose/Moose.so conflicts between attempted installs of Moose-Util-2.2013-1.x86_64 and Moose-Util-TypeConstraints-2.2013-1.x86_64
  file /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/Moose/Moose.so conflicts between attempted installs of Moose-Meta-TypeConstraint-2.2013-1.x86_64 and Moose-Util-2.2013-1.x86_64
  file /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/Moose/Moose.so conflicts between attempted installs of Moose-Meta-TypeConstraint-Union-2.2013-1.x86_64 and Moose-Meta-TypeConstraint-2.2013-1.x86_64
  file /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/Moose/Moose.so conflicts between attempted installs of Moose-Util-MetaRole-2.2013-1.x86_64 and Moose-Meta-TypeConstraint-Union-2.2013-1.x86_64
  file /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/Moose/Moose.so conflicts between attempted installs of Moose-Meta-Attribute-2.2013-1.x86_64 and Moose-Util-MetaRole-2.2013-1.x86_64
  file /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/Moose/Moose.so conflicts between attempted installs of Moose-Meta-Class-2.2013-1.x86_64 and Moose-Meta-Attribute-2.2013-1.x86_64
  file /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/Moose/Moose.so conflicts between attempted installs of Moose-Meta-Role-2.2013-1.x86_64 and Moose-Meta-Class-2.2013-1.x86_64
  file /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/Moose/Moose.so conflicts between attempted installs of Moose-Meta-Role-Attribute-2.2013-1.x86_64 and Moose-Meta-Role-2.2013-1.x86_64
  file /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/HTML/Parser/Parser.so conflicts between attempted installs of HTML-HeadParser-3.75-1.x86_64 and HTML-Entities-3.75-1.x86_64
```

I've spent days trying to debug the issue but I can't seem to figure it out. All I did was install perl using yum since that was a prerequisite. I expected my local install would work.

Comment: You may find that a simpler way of deploying a Perl application is to install a copy of Perl using [perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/) instead of using the system Perl, and use [carton](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carton) to manage packaging up modules for your application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message seems clear: you can't have two packages providing the same file.

For the errors around `Moose.so`, you would probably want to move the shared library into a separate package and make it a dependency of all the modules that require it.

For the errors around `HTML-HeadParser`, I think you would simply have a `HTML-Parser` package and that make things like `HTML-HeadParser` and `HTML-Entitities` depend on it.

Maybe take some time and look at how the existing Perl modules are packaged?  For example, look at:

- [perl-HTML-Parser](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/perl-HTML-Parser/blob/master/f/perl-HTML-Parser.spec)
- [perl-HTML-Entities-Interpolate](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/perl-HTML-Entities-Interpolate/blob/master/f/perl-HTML-Entities-Interpolate.spec)
- [perl-Moose](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/perl-Moose/blob/master/f/perl-Moose.spec) and all the other `perl-Moose-*` and `perl-MooseX-*` packages in the same repository.

Comment: So it seems I don't have enough experience with RPM packages. I tried playing around with the depencies while using fpm but I lack the knowledge.

So am I supposed to add a single RPM and add all required Moose submodules in it?

Comment: @Serban Cezar, No, "you would probably want to move the shared library" (e.g. Moose) "into a separate package". The sub modules would have a dependency the Moose RPM

Comment: @ikegami I'm not sure how I would go about that with RPMs. I guess I need to add the 'depends' property and then the submodules would know not to override the same package? So does that mean I need to bundle more than 1 Perl module in an RPM? Is that possible?

Comment: @Serban Cezar, Re "*So does that mean I need to bundle more than 1 Perl module in an RPM?*", Again, we're telling you do exactly the opposite of that. That's what you're doing, and that's what's causing you problems. Create different RPMs for different distros.

Comment: @ikegami Well that's what I did. I created a RPM package for each Perl module and submodule. And I thought that this is the cause of the library conflict. So am I not supposed to create a RPM for the Moose module and other RPMs for the submodules and have them depend on the root one? Because I don't think that's what you're suggesting and I think I've misunderstood.

Comment: This really isn't that complicated: two packages can't provide the same file (and be installed at the same time). If you are getting file conflicts, either you've erroneously included a file in a package **or** that file should be moved to a new package that becomes a common dependency.

Comment: @Serban Cezar, Re "*I created a RPM package for each Perl module and submodule*", No, you created RPM packages that contained multiple Perl distros. Specifically, the Moose module/distro was found in multiple RPM packages.

Comment: @ikegami I managed to solve my problem by using the 'provides' macro with fpm so that all the Moose submodules are provided by the Moose-2 distro. I was thus able to install all my bundled modules using rpm. I'm not not sure if that's what I was supposed to do but it's a legacy application so I can't afford to waste too much time on it.